# Android Form Validation - Showing the Error Messages on top

Tags: android, validation, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a form with some textview and text field after clicking on button I will get an error messages, I want to show the error messages on top of the form, would you please let me know how can I implement like a below picture?

instead of setError I want to show the error on top!

Appreciated any hints, documentation or sample code!

thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not right way show error for input validation,why you are hold useless view for showing only error for input(like website).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is add the `TextView` above your `TextFields` and set its Visibility to `GONE`. And after you hit the button and recieve the error set the `TextView's` Visibility to `VISIBLE`.

add this **top** of your `TextFields`:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/your_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

**sample:**

```
your_textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //to set textview visible
```

Also you need to set the text of your textView if name is not filled just set the text for name error.

**error:**

set the text of your TextView

**1 error:**

```
your_textview.setText("Name: Please fill this field")
```

**2 error**

```
your_textview.setText("Name: Please fill this field\nComments: Please fill this field")
```

just use the line break delimeter "\n" after each error

You need to check each of the field if it is empty:

```
String error = "";
if(field1.getText().equals(""))
   error += "field 1 fill the form\n";
if(field2.getText().equals(""))
   error += "field 2 fill the form\n";
.
.
.
and so on.

your_textview.setText(error);
```

Comment: thanks for comment, I update my question,and how should I print setError messages there?

Comment: @JonHudson which one are you asking is it the, please fill out this field?

Comment: @JonHudson I dont really follow you, " how should I print setError messages there?", you already have form_status_header_view use it for your error and set the text.

Comment: how can I print it there, I mean if I have 3 error how can I print them there, would you please add it in your answer

Comment: thanks but what if I had 5 error in 5 textView how can I print them in one textView?

Comment: @JonHudson just add '\n' each you add an error. just like above.

Comment: is there another way? since I don't know which field would be appear, if I had 12 textView in my form ?